# Microsoft word - automatic text shift above the table

Tags: microsoft-word

We are writing scientific text in Microsoft word which includes many tables. When the table is too big it is moved to another page. Thus between the text above the table and the table the blank gap is created. We would like to fill in the gap with the text from below the table. We can do that of course manually but because we have many these kind of tables we hope that MS word can do that automatically. Is this possible ? If yes, how ? Please help us !!!

Two pictures below describe how we would like that the text look before and after changes.

Before changes:

[image]

After changes:

[image]

Comment: Are you allowing your tables to break across pages? NB: edit your post, the images are not showing up.

Comment: you should really be writing reports like this in Publisher _not_ Word

Comment: Sorry, something went wrong and hyperlinks were not included.

Comment: For some reasons we really would like that the table stays without breaking between pages.

Comment: Change the word wrapping options of the table. I think its in "Table properties" -> Text wrapping.